# Export React Components dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to add some extra properties/functionality to my components using HOC and then export them.

I have a `HOCWrapper` component that is a HOC, that is implemented like mentioned [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html).

**index.js**

```
import * as all from './AllMyComponents'

let AllChangedComponents = Object.keys(all).map((key) => {
    return all[key] = HOCWrapper(all[key]);
})

export default AllChangedComponents;
```

And the use the like:

**another.js** file

```
import {MyComponent} from './index'
```

This is not working when trying to export dynamically the components,

Its is possible to export dynamically?

Comment: let AllChangedComponents = Object.keys(all).map((key) => {
    return all[key] = HOCWrapper(all[key]);

You have converted what used to be an object to an array.

So you need to spit out a new object instead. Something more like this

let wrappedObjects = {};

Object.keys(all).forEach((key) => {
    wrappedObjects[key] = HOCWrapper(all[key]);
}

export wrappedObjects;

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do `import {MyComponent}`; that only works if `MyComponent` was statically exported from `index.js`.

Since `MyComponent` is instead a member of an object that is being exported from `index.js`, you need to import that object and destructure it into local variables:

```
import wrapped from "./index";
const { MyComponent } = wrapped;
```

Another issue here is that your wrapping code doesn't make any sense. Instead of computing an object with wrapped functions, you're trying to mutate the original import (which is only visible in the module's own scope, and doesn't affect anyone else who imports `./AllMyComponents`).

You should do:

```
const AllChangedComponents = Object.keys(all)
  .map(k => ({ [k]: HOCWrapper(all[k]) }))
  .reduce((l, r) => ({ ...l, ...r }))
```